# Creating nuanced android actionbar gradients (as seen on foursquare, instagram)

Tags: android, user-interface, gradient, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to generate the nuanced gradients as seen on applications like foursquare (left) and instagram (right):

[image: foursquare] [image: instagram]

I have generated a simple gradient for an actionbar using illustrator and also using basic android shapes. My gradient unfortunately looks like this:

[image: my boring gradient]

It lacks the "spackled" nuances found in the aforementioned actionbars and replaces it with an unfortunate "streaking", and I am wondering if there is a method in android to programmatically generate such gradients, or if anyone has any tips on creating such gradients using illustrator/photoshop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the streaking you mention here?

Comment: the horizontal lines of uniform color that span across the shape. The speckling breaks that up.

Comment: Here is a link about photoshop http://www.photoshopgurus.com/forum/forum-tutorials/1500-speckles-difference-gradients.html

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that any applications generate these on the fly but am happy to be proven wrong.

You might check a site like http://subtlepatterns.com which has creative commons licensed spackle that might fit your need wholesale or with some moderate tweaking.

Comment: That's the only one I'm familiar with, I've seen many background sites but none of them post their license up front.  I use openclipart.org for other open license graphics, not just backgrounds.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to create such gradients myself, but interesting site nonetheless. More along the lines of patterns than gradients.